# How to change/set values of a mapping through a function in solidity?

Tags: solidity, evm, arrays, mapping, struct

I have the following structure, with the mentioned mapping

```
    struct A
    {
        uint a;
        bool[100] b;
    }
    
    mapping(uint => A) public arr;
```

I am using this function to set/change the values of the above mapping

```
    function B(uint _x, uint _y) public
    {
        arr[x].a++;
        arr[x].b[y]=true;
    }
```

But I am getting no output. Somehow the change is not getting reflected. Am I doing it wrong? Would love suggestions and changes to my code snippet.

I would be grateful for the help. Tia.

Please mention in comments if you need further clarification.

Addition to my question: I am thinking, maybe the issue is the way I am retrieving the values? If that is so, this is how I am retrieving the values. Suppose my contract name is C. Here is how I am testing:

```
truffle migrate --reset
truffle console
C.deployed().then(function(instance) { app = instance })
app.B(1234).then(function(c) { t = c; })
```

Now, after running these, I am expecting t[0] to give 1. But it is giving nothing(undefined).

PS- 1234 is any value I am using as a test index for the mentioned mapping.

Comment: My guess is that you are using a `call` when setting the values, instead of a real tranaction. The state changes are not permanent when using a `call`.

Comment: I got to know this is the error which you stated. Thank you so much for pointing it out. Actually I am new to solidity, can you please let me know what is the process for the same?